# c++ array with multiple objects

Tags: c++, object, struct, multidimensional-array

So I am creating a simple game map initialized as follows:

```
char map[MAP_SIZE][MAP_SIZE];
```

Now, as you can see, right now it is of just char. The problem is, I want the map to hold different types of objects instead. This is what I did so far but I wanted to see if there was a more efficient way(which there probably is).

```
class Treasure{};
class Chest{};
class Enemy{};
class Grunt : public Enemy{};
class Lieutenant : public Enemy{};
class Boss : public Enemy{};
class Final_Boss : public Enemy{};
class Secret_Room{};
class Map_Level{};

struct Entity
{
   char display_char; //Simple character that is displayed on the the map
   Treasure *t;
   Chest *c;
   Grunt *g;
   Lieutenant *l;
   Boss *b;
   Final_Boss *f;
   Secret_Room *s;
   Map_Level *u;
   Map_Level *d;
};

Entity map[MAP_SIZE][MAP_SIZE];
```

I thought about just checking the display_char and depending on what it is, just deleting the object pointers I don't need but that seems like a lot of unnecessary work. I hope this question is clear enough and would appreciate any help figuring out the best way to do this.

Comment: You could have everything inherit off of base class `Entity` and just have `Entity map[][]`

Comment: @awesomeyi: Well, it'd have to be Entity pointers or you'd be slicing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want one enemy per `map` entry, you could just have a `Enemy *` instead of having the whole list of `Grunt, Lieutenant`, etc.

Comment: This gave me an idea that will help me out significantly. Thanks for the help!!